# How can i create a directory in drive C:\?

Tags: vb.net, security, windows-7, permissions, create-directory

i am trying to create a directory in drive C: (at a win7 target machine) with `Directory.CreateDirectory` but so far no luck.

I believe the problem has to do something with permissions-security... So here i am..

How can i create a directory in drive C?

Comment: I believe you can't unless you are running in a user-account which has the required permissions on C:. If any app could create folders in your root folder, the world would be a less safer place...

Comment: Not an answer as such, but I'd suggest not creating the directory in the root of C: but instead considering using one of the recommended locations for storing application data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use the root of C for an ordinary application. If you're just using it because you think it's a folder you can count on, use AppData or Temp instead. If this is not an ordinary application, but is instead an administrative application, then put a manifest on it requesting it elevate (requireAdministrator) so that it can gain access to the areas of the hard drive and registry protected by UAC.

Comment: For the dummies out there like me, i edited the app.manifest file, from 

<requestedExecutionLevel  level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" /> to 
<requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />

Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 5):

You need to run your application in elevated mode (via UAC). How this can be done is shown in the above StackOverflow thread:

[UAC, Vista and C# - Programatically requesting elevation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282448/uac-vista-and-c-programatically-requesting-elevation)

Before executing the code to switch in elevated mode you should do a check if you application is running on Vista, Windows 7 or above.

Comment: I would not partition the app as a first choice. It's more work than a simple manifest and if the app always needs to do the elevated thing it is complexity for no reason. Partitioning is probably my third choice.

Answer (score 0):

DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\MyDir");
 dir.Create();
hope this will help u...