# Visual Studio Setup Project Produce Output File that use Highest Privilege

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-server-2008

How do I preset the output exe with the highest privilege checked? I am having issues for the application running on Windows 7 or Windows 2008, if the user did not select Run As Administrator, the application crashed.

Is there a way to preset the privilege?

Regards

PlayKid

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282448/windows-7-and-vista-uac-programatically-requesting-elevation-in-c/2282613#2282613) answer

Answer (score 0):

The recommended approach is to add a manifest which requests Administrator privileges:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx