# WPF application - ask for administrator rights in runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, runtime, administrator, rights

Only a few options in my WPF application, need administrator rights. I'd like to avoid compulsion to run the program as an administrator, so is there any opportunity to ask for administrator privileges in runtime, only in case of operation which requires this privileges?

Comment: This is really old, but does it answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/2282613/982149

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can elevate an existing process.  But I found a way in powershell 5 to start my script in a new elevated process.  Hope this helps

```
# Get the ID and security principal of the current user account
$myWindowsID = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent();
$myWindowsPrincipal = New-Object System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal($myWindowsID);

# Get the security principal for the administrator role
$adminRole = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator;

# Check to see if we are currently running as an administrator
if ($myWindowsPrincipal.IsInRole($adminRole))
{
    # We are running as an administrator, so change the title and background colour to indicate this
    $Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = $myInvocation.MyCommand.Definition + "(Elevated)";
    $Host.UI.RawUI.BackgroundColor = "DarkBlue";
    Clear-Host;
}
else
{
    # We are not running as an administrator, so relaunch as administrator

    # Create a new process object that starts PowerShell
    $newProcess = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo "PowerShell";

    # Specify the current script path and name as a parameter with added scope and support for scripts with spaces in it's path
    $newProcess.Arguments = "& '" + $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path + "'"

    # Indicate that the process should be elevated
    $newProcess.Verb = "runas";

    # Start the new process
    [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($newProcess);

    # Exit from the current, unelevated, process
    Exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add to your project Application Manifest File (app.manifest) 
and set **requestedExecutionLevel** to **highestAvailable**"/>

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app"/
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <!-- UAC Manifest Options
             If you want to change the Windows User Account Control level replace the 
             requestedExecutionLevel node with one of the following. -->


        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />

        <!-- requestedExecutionLevel  level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" /-->
        <!-- requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" /-->

      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

Comment: Well, it's not what I want to reach. Today when I was installing VirtualBox, installer asked me for administrator rights while installation process, not at start and I'm curious how have they achived that, because I need something similar in my program.

Comment: At runtime, you would have to create a new process of your application, which is running with administrator privileges.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a manifest file to the following location.

[image: Manifest location]

2. Change Line 19 to the following code in manifest.

`<requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />`

3. It will prompt for administrator right upon starting up.

Comment: Well, it's not what I want because as I said, I'd like to avoid compulsion to run the program as an administrator. Only in case of operations which need admin rights I'd like to please user for admin rights.